# How to use getSharedPreferences outside method?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to initialize SharedPreferences CODE using **getSharedPreferences() outside method**, but failed(inside method success), below is the error info. How to fix?

> "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference"

.

I marked "not work" in below code:

```
    public class temp extends FragmentActivity {

    //below not work
    SharedPreferences CODE = getSharedPreferences("CODE", MODE_PRIVATE);

    //below also not work
    SharedPreferences CODE;
    {
        CODE= getSharedPreferences("CODE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //work
        SharedPreferences CODE = getSharedPreferences("CODE", MODE_PRIVATE);

        // also work
        CODE = getSharedPreferences("CODE", MODE_PRIVATE); // defined CODE as class member

    }
}
```

Comment: *How to fix?* don't do it

Comment: It should be called on a `context` variable!

Comment: I tried getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CODE", MODE_PRIVATE), still not work

Answer (score 0):

make another class,used only for getting and setting shared preference,though you may need to change code a bit by your need(such as passing context in constructor)

```
public class SharedPreference extends Activity{
    public  SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("TEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    public  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
    public SharedPreferences getPreference() {
        return preference;
    }

    public SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor() {
        return editor;
    }
}
```

and you can access it anywhere like

```
SharedPreference pref = new SharedPreference();
SharedPreferences preference = pref.getPreference();
```